# How do I deal with exceptions in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, for-loop

Here is an example of a random piece of python loop code:

```
for j in range(5):
    try:
        cats = raw_input("Enter age of your five cats")

    except ValueError:
        print ("Try again")
```

The problem I have with this code is that when ever the except line is triggered, my loop does not completely reset itself. What happens is that when I get an exception, the exception itself counts as 1 for the range..

More specific:

Lets say the user does not trigger exception and we get these 5 age inputs **5 4 5 3 2** (range 5), however if we do trigger an exception then the user is only allowed to enter 4 ages **5 4 5 3** because for some reason the exception counts towards the range count..Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: You could use a while loop instead `while(input_count < 5)` and only increment `input_count` for each successful entry.

Comment: Try this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470233/python-loop-exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
for j in range (5):
    badCat = True
    while badCat:
        try:
            cats[j] = int (raw_input ("Enter age of cat # %d: " % (j + 1)))
            badCat = False
        except ValueError:
            print ("Try again")
```

This will stay on a single cat until you enter a "proper" age.

You'll notice I've wrapped an `int()` around your input function call. I assume that's what you were going to do eventually since I'm pretty certain `raw_input()` doesn't throw `ValueError` on its own.

I've also stored the age of the cat in an array since your code will only ever remember the last age entered.

You can remove the need for a separate variable (if you're worried about that sort of thing (which I tend not to be)) by making a slight modification:

```
for j in range (5):
    while True:
        try:
            cats[j] = int (raw_input ("Enter age of cat # %d: " % (j + 1)))
            break;
        except ValueError:
            print ("Try again")
```

Comment: Hmm, your method does work, but I tried to mess with it and instead of doing "badCat = True" and "while badCat:". I tried doing "while True" instead, but for some reason I get myself into an infinite loop. Why doesn't my method of "while True" work?

Comment: @user152573: probably because you wrote it instead of me :-) No, seriously, I'd have to see the code. The _likelihood_ is that you're not breaking from the loop after the input.

Comment: Can you explain how the badCat = True and badCat = False fixes this issue？When does the badCat = False trigger and what does it exactly do?

Comment: @user152573, `badCat` is simply the control variable for the inner loop, the `while` one. As long as `badCat` is true, it will continue to ask you for the age of a single cat, not advance to the next one. At the point where `int(raw_input(blah blah))` does _not_ generate an exception, it will then set `badCat` to false and the `while` loop will exit, advancing to the next cat. If the exception occurs, `badCat` is not changed and it will ask you about the same cat again. And again. And again, until you enter something valid.

Comment: @user152573, I've added the variant that you seem to be working towards, one that uses `while true/break` rather than using a control variable.

Comment: Arghh, your second solution just made me realize why my initial method failed. I had inadvertently switched the first two lines or code around and as a result it gave me an infinite loop even with the break sign. Thank you for coincidentally solving my other problem. I did while loop first and then the for loop >.>.

Answer (score 1):

Stay in a `while` loop inside of your `for` loop until you get the input you want.

```
for j in range(5):
    input_ok = False
    while not input_ok:
        try:
            cats = raw_input("Enter age of your five cats")
            input_ok = True
        except ValueError:
            print ("Try again")
```

This way you will only enter the next iteration of your outer `for` loop when you get a valid cat age value.

Comment: Your answer and the first answer are similar, but how come you use False first instead of True like Paxdiablo has done? Does it matter? Also like I asked Paxdiablo, how come when I use the line "while True" instead of doing the False and True thing I end up in a infinite loop?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I like to boolean predicate to set to `False` (input_ok), until I can set it to `True`.

Comment: so the input_ok = True triggers and works to end the while loop after 5 successful raw inputs?

Comment: No, you only exit the while loop when you get one successful raw_input. Then it moves on to the next of the 5 for loop iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...

```
for j in range(5):
    while True:
        try:
            cats = raw_input("Enter age of your five cats")
            break

        except ValueError:
            print ("Try again")
```